# Nginx regular expression name error with dnsmasq

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to configure Nginx to use wildcard subdomains on `.local`, where the subdomain is also the name of the folder. For example, `test-site.local:8080` should have a location root of `/Users/ashley/www/sites/test-site/wwwdata` and `another.local:8080` should be `/Users/ashley/www/sites/another/wwwdata`.

I've set the following configuration in `nginx.conf`, as per [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names):

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  mbp.local ~^(?<domain>.+)\.local$;

    location / {
        root   /Users/ashley/www/sites/$domain/wwwroot;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

This does not work (site cannot be reached) and if I check the error.log, I get no error message. However, `mbp.local` does generate an error:

`2018/01/18 18:30:57 [error] 4968#0: *1 "/Users/ashley/www/sites//wwwroot/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.10, server: mbp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mbp.local:8080"`

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I've removed `mbp.local` from the `server_name` as I guess it's not matching on the regex, hence no `$domain` variable being passed to the location. If I now try a subdomain, there is no error entry. Based on the site cannot be reached error in the browser and the lack of entry, I can only assume that the DNS lookup is failing. I'm using dnsmasq to resolve `.local` URL's, which is working fine:

```
dig another.local @127.0.0.1
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;another.local.         IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
another.local.      0   IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

I've no DNS servers configured in my network settings and adding `127.0.0.1` doesn't do it - just causes all DNS lookups to fail. Any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was neither an Nginx (apart from the errant `mbp.local`) nor dnsmasq issue, but a macOS network configuration problem.

I needed to add `.local` as a search domain in my network preferences.